# Swift 2 sorting - Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type…

Tags: sorting, swift2

I have a class, say `Penguin`

```
class Penguin {
   var beakLength: Float
}
```

Trying to sort an array of `Penguins` as follows:

```
let penguins = [Penguin]()
let sortedPenguins = penguins.sort { $0.beakLength < $1.beakLength }
```

gives error message:

> Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '(@noescape
>   (Penguin, Penguin) -> Bool)'
>
> Expected an argument list of type '(@noescape (Self.Generator.Element,
>   Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool)'

What am I missing here?

Comment: It works in my Playground ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOzUny30na5PLYz4Y781afHdBJ7JU-j5Xp0)).

Comment: That's odd - it does for me too… but it won't compile

Comment: The errors you show can't come from this simple snippet, it works as it is. So there's probably something else in your project about your class or your sort function that you're not showing. Please edit your question with relevant pieces of your actual code.

Comment: Correct - works fine in the playground, gives the errors above when compiling source. There is more to the class, I was trying to give a simplified example, but using the full class in the playground also works. I agree that there must be something else - I was hoping this question would help me find out what it was!

Comment: `the full class in the playground also works` This, for me, means that you definitely have something in your project which conflicts with your class. An overloaded operator, for example, or inheritance/conformance problems.

Comment: Haha!! Got it!! The result of the sort was being assigned to a variable of the wrong type. Thanks for your input. I'll leave this open as a memorial to my stupidity!

Comment: Cool! You're welcome.

Comment: @Ashley Mills..."memorial to my stupidity"...cannot upvote you enough, brother...your memorial was my mirror, reflecting my own, identical, stupidity :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem, it turns out the code sample above wasn't quite correct. What was *actually* more like:

```
var sortedPenguins = [Chimp]()

let penguins = [Penguin]()
sortedPenguins = penguins.sort { $0.beakLength < $1.beakLength }
```

**D'oh!**

Comment: Run into the same issue today. The compiler gives a totally misleading error message.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in **Swift 3**, the *sort* function performs an "in place" sort and does not return a value (`mutating func sort()`).  To create a sorted copy of the original array you now use *sorted* (`func sorted() -> [Element]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Penguin : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return beakLength.description }
    var beakLength: Float
    init(length: Float){
        beakLength = length
    }
}


var penguins = [Penguin]()
penguins.append(Penguin(length: 10))
penguins.append(Penguin(length: 20))
penguins.append(Penguin(length: 5))
print(penguins)
print(penguins.sort { $0.beakLength < $1.beakLength })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Sort is deprecated in **swift3** 
you can try this code for max-character count in an array.

```
let Penguin = ["as","asc","you","bce","csi","aasi","aaas","this"]
let maxLen = penguin.sorted{ $0.characters.count > $1.characters.count}
 print(maxLen)
```

The result should be 
["aasi", "aaas", "this", "asc", "you", "bce", "csi", "as"]

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer my question.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that in swift its "Sorted" instead of "sort" for objective c. like you could use penguin.sorted { $0.characters.count > $1.characters.count}